# Add toc entries for html generated in r chunks in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

The explicit headers I add to a Rmd file (e.g. ## Section 1) are recognised fine using yaml like this:

```
---
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    toc: true
---
```

But if my code generates html output that includes header elements like `<h3>` etc, then they are ignored in the toc. How can I get them to be included?

````
```{r results='asis'}
# either through cat
cat(paste0('<h3>', 'some header', '</h3>'))
# or via some function's output
summarytools::print.summarytools(
    summarytools::dfSummary(df), headings = TRUE, method = 'render')
```
````

I'm knitting the file in RStudio.

```
## R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

## other attached packages:
##  [1] diffobj_0.3.0      knitr_1.29         summarytools_0.9.6 assertthat_0.2.1  
##  [5] forcats_0.5.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.2        purrr_0.3.4       
##  [9] readr_1.3.1        tidyr_1.1.2        tibble_3.0.3       ggplot2_3.3.2     
## [13] tidyverse_1.3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of raw HTML, have your `results="asis"` block output *markdown*.

````
---
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    toc: true
---

# Header1

## Header2

### Header3a

```{r echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
cat('\n\n### Header3b\n\n')
```

```{r}
"something goes here"
```
````

[image: r-markdown rendered to html with table of contents]

Comment: Thanks, that half works! Good for `cat` but I'm also using `summarytools` to write out reports and it doesn't seem to have the facility to render its output as markdown, so I get html output in a markdown block. The problem is with the function I'm using. I might need to just find a different way of doing this.

Comment: I thought the question was about getting a header into the TOC. I don't know `summarytools`, but [the docs](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools#dfsummary) that mention rmarkdown do not specifically say to use `results="asis"`. Break out the header and output code into different chunks. See my edit. If this doesn't work, please accept this answer and ask one specifically about that package within rmarkdown (since it's not about yaml/toc/'asis'), thanks.